# Installing JCL for C++Builder 6 in a Windows XP virtual machine (VirtualBox)

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am trying to install JCL in an XP VM where I have previously installed Borland C++Builder 6.

When I run `install.bat`, it says:

> No Delphi/BCB/BDS verson installed.

But it is installed in `C:/Programs/Borland/CBuilder6`

Any help?

Comment: What does `Install.bat` look like? Is it hard-coded to look for BCB in C:\Program Files\`? Is it looking for BCB via an environment variable that is missing/misconfigured? Need more details to diagnose the problem.

Comment: it calls build/dcc32ex.exe (build is a folder on the jcl set of folders). I do no think C++ Builder 6 is misconfigured because it works for anything else

Comment: I didn't say BCB was misconfigured. I said your VM environment might be. But since we don't know what `install.bat` is actually looking for, there is no way to diagnose your problem.

Comment: by `C:/Programs/Borland/CBuilder6`  you mean `C:/Programs Files/Borland/CBuilder6` or `C:/Programs Files (x86)/Borland/CBuilder6` ? 32bit or 64bit XP ?

Comment: yes, right, because in italian installation the path is C:\Programmi\... so I wrongly translate it instead of using C:\Program Files\....

Answer (score 0):

I did not solve the problem but I was able to manually install JCL building all the packages one by one. Now I will try to install JVCL, I already know it hs the same installer problem.